# cannot use children (type []Child) as type []Node in argument to func

Tags: go

Here is my test code

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Node interface {
    sayHello()
}

type Parent struct {
    Name string
}

type Child struct {
    Parent
    Age int
}

type Children []Child

func (p Parent) sayHello() {
    fmt.Printf("Hello my name is %s\n", p.Name)
}

func (p Child) sayHello() {
    fmt.Printf("Hello my name is %s and I'm %d\n", p.Name, p.Age)
}

func makeSayHello(n Node) {
    n.sayHello()
}

func sayHellos(list []Node) {
    for _, p := range list {
        makeSayHello(p)
    }
}

func main() {

    children := []Child{Child{Parent: Parent{Name: "Bart"}, Age: 8}, Child{Parent: Parent{Name: "Lisa"}, Age: 9}}

    for _, c := range children {
        c.sayHello()
    }

    makeSayHello( Parent{"Homer"} )
    sayHellos( []Node{Parent{"Homer"}} )
    sayHellos( []Node{Parent{"Homer"},Child{Parent:Parent{"Maggy"},Age:3}} )


    sayHellos( children )   // error : cannot use children (type []Child) as type []Node in argument to sayHellos
}
```

link https://play.golang.org/p/7IZLoXjlIK

I don't get it. Let's say I have a []Child I cannot modify and I want use it with un function accepting []Parent. Why do I have an type error ?

If I can't or don't want this solution by changing

```
children := []Child{...}
```

to

```
children := []Node{...}
```

What can I do to transform the []Child to []Node ? It is not already ? Do I have to do another []Node to copy my elements in ?
I naïvely try children.([]Node) or []Node(children) without success ...

Comment: See also https://golang.org/doc/faq#convert_slice_of_interface. And please stop thinking of inheritance and parent-child-relation. Go has absolutely no notion of inheritance and embedding is a) not inheritance and b) not suitable to mimic inheritance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An array of structs (such as `[]Child`) has very different memory layout comparing to an array of interfaces (such as `[]Node`). So Go doesn't do `[]Child` to `[]Node` conversion implicitly, you have to do it yourself:

```
nodes := make([]Node, len(children), len(children))
for i := range children {
    nodes[i] = children[i]
}
sayHellos(nodes)
```

BTW in the example you provided it would be more efficient to call `sayHello` directly:

```
for _, child := range children {
    child.sayHello()
}
```

Probably this is what you should do in your program as well.

Comment: nitpick, it's called a slice not an array.

Comment: "an array that backs up a slice" would be even more accurate